# display randomly freezing (mouse still works) long term issue happens on both ubuntu 14 and mint 18

Tags: display

I have a fresh install of mint 18.2 however this mint install replaced ubuntu 14.4 and the identical issue happened with ubuntu

machine specs here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/622f9d3cebc52391ffda331423d498ce

When it locks up only the mouse pointer can move. Programs keep running, music keeps playing, just interaction with the desktop is impossible and screen is not updated (except the mouse pointer). Plex will continue to stream a video to my tv, everything seems to work except I can do nothing...lol

No matter what I try I cannot do anything other than hit the reset button (or Alt + SysRq + b)

This happens randomly, sometimes I can go days or weeks and everything works, then it starts locking up every day for a week... I have found many posts about this going back at least 4 years and no solution.

As I mentioned this happened on my install of ubuntu 14.4 I was running that (for years) until I just changed to mint, and exactly the same problem happens. I have had up to date software, out of date software, up to date kernels and out of date and it still happens.

One thing I have seen that seems fairly common is that I (and many others) will click on a random link or button on the screen and at the point of the actual click... freeze

It seems to happen with nvidia cards, but I cant say its only those I have seen mention of mostly those in searching on and off about this over the last few years.

I have used the nvidia drivers and the non nvidia drivers on ubuntu to the same result but only the xorg drivers on this mint install and its still happening.

I know this is not a very technically based post Im not really sure where to start. This has been very random and over time when its worse than others I have tried to figure it out and as mentioned found its a long term issue.

The fact its happening on ubuntu and carried over to mint, the only things I can see in common are the underlying ubuntu software on both and the nvidia video cards, but those have used at this point a number of different drivers to the same result..

Suggestions on how to figure this out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Install the recommended Nvidia drivers for your card.

Comment: this has happened with both nvidia drivers and the non nvidia drivers, so they arent the cause.. 

I have had many issues caused by the nvidia drivers over the years and will not use them, and since the issue has happened with and without them, they cant really be the cause

Comment: If you're using an incorrect version then yes, expect problems. If however the problem is constant and similar no matter which driver version you're using than your problem is HARDWARE. You may try updating UEFI though.